# USB OTG and USB Hub on PI Zero

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I would like to use the Pi Zero with a few USB devices (WiFi, TV Tuner, external HDD) plugged into it while at the same time using OTG USB CDC drivers to make the Pi Zero appear as an Ethernet connection in a desktop PC. I have seen USB hubs but these appear to take over the usb connector on the Pi zero.

And yes, I know I could use the Ethernet hat then a USB to Ethernet in the PC or have the Pi be a WiFi hotspot for connection. The Ethernet is additional cables as power would also have to be provided and the WiFi is more flakey.

Comment: Or you could just use a proper Pi with Ethernet & a hub, because what you propose is impossible.

Comment: As Milliways points out, you are either a USB slave or a USB master, not both at the same time.

Comment: So no chipsets/hubs have a OTG port + normal master ports?

Answer (score 0):

There are USB adaptor hats (or a cable) for Raspberry Pi zero they allow you to plug in the Raspberry PI into your computer (and be power by) as if the Raspberry PI is a Network adaptor.

Which means your host computer can access you RPI0 over network in terms of ssh/NFS/Samba etc.

Add the following to your config.txt
dtoverlay=dwc2

Add the following to your cmdline.txt
modules-load=dwc2,g_ether

Tutorial here with pictures.
https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The hats you are suggesting only allow the RPI to act as a USB slave, not as dual slave and master.

Comment: I've configured my USB gadget RPI0-W into a network device at which point I use dnsmaqd to assign it a IP address and I that allows connectivity in both directions.    I can login from the PI to the HOST computer and vs a versa.